# What's mysql-devel here for?

Tags: mysql

```
yum install mysql
yum install mysql-server
yum install mysql-devel
```

I think `mysql` is a client and `mysql-server` is server side,

but what's `mysql-devel` for?

BTW,how to change the new installed mysql password to `psw` ?

Comment: wamp - you better get into the habit of marking answers as accepted or you will stop getting answers from people. You've asked 15 questions and have accepted a grand total of 0 of the answers given.

Comment: I think it's time for you to start reading the docs.

Answer (score 4):

`*-devel` packages (whether mysql or otherwise) provide the shared libraries necessary if you want to compile any other apps that require these libraries. If all you're doing is installing from your distro's package repo, then you most likely don't need to worry about the -devel packages.

Comment: I'm not a Linux user, but in BSD land -devel means it's a development version (Alpha or Beta software usually)

Comment: It means that in Linux land as well.  It's simply a naming convention used by RedHat style packages and is not indicative of how things are named as a whole.